# AutoMapper doesn't map source to a destination

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I don't know why, at some point AutoMapper doesn't map source to a destination object.

```
   var result = Mapper.Map<User, User>(userToImport, userToUpdate);
   var areEquals = result == userToUpdate; //FALSE !!! Why?
   var areEquals2 = result.Equals(userToUpdate); //FALSE !!! Why?
```

`userToUpdate` is not updated with new values from userToImport. `result`  is a correct resulting object of mapping. But `result` and `userToUpdate` are different objects.

The main problem is, why `userToUpdate` is not updated?

Comment: How are `==` and `Equals` implemented?

Comment: If you do not create the map first Mapper.CreateMap<User, User>(); the destination object will not be filled with the values of the source object, but the returning object will be filled. Also, you are comparing 2 different references and that will return false in this case. You need to override operator == or Equals function and do your comparison logic (this.prop1 == obj.prop1)

Comment: @leskovar Mapper.Map<,>() returns the SAME reference specified in the destination argument. So a comparison with either Equals or == will result in true if a map exists (See my answer). No overriding is needed, the problem lies in the missing CreateMap.

Comment: @Alex yes, exactly I have not called CreateMap. This was the cause why I've got such behavior. And it was weird for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll have to create a map first or else it won't update and return the object of the destination parameter.

```
 Mapper.CreateMap<User, User>();
```

Comment: This actually turns out to be true. I'm a bit surprised that AM doesn't throw an exception when the mapping is not created.

Comment: I suspect you are right. Because it worked for me in the past. I will check and get back to you later. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

You need to do something like this:

```
public class User
{
    public int Property1 { get; set; }
    public int Property2 { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (!(obj is User))
            return false;
        else
        {
            Usero = obj as User;
            return o.Property1 == this.Property1 && o.Property2 == this.Property2;
        }

    }
}
```

After that you can do `obj1.Equals(obj2);`

Comment: This has nothing to do with it. AutoMapper.Map(source,destination) returns the destination object.